# Powershell how to search the file and then open then tail the file based on the first search

Tags: powershell

How do open tail the first text file I search in descending order?

```
Get-Content -Tail
```

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Path "C:\*.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -lt (Get-Date).Date } | Sort CreationTime -Descending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -First 1` to discard everything after the first input object:

```
Get-ChildItem ... |Where-Object {...} | Sort ... |Select-Object -First 1 |Get-Content -Tail
```